# PHP - Grabbing items of an array except for last index

Tags: php, arrays, slice

I was wondering if there is any way to grab all items in array except for last index, like in Python you can do

```
>>> a = [1,2,3,4,5]
>>> a[:-1]
[1,2,3,4]
```

I tried `array_slice($a, -1)` and it doesn't work, also best if it can be done without knowing an array's length.

Comment: `array_slice($a, 0, -1);`, always read the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to specify an offset and an negative length for this to work:

```
$array = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
$array = array_slice($array, 0, -1);
print_r($array);
// will display Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 [2] => 3 [3] => 4 )
```

Of course you could also use `array_pop()` to remove the last element from the array:

```
array_pop($array);
print_r($array);
// will display Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 [2] => 3 [3] => 4 )
```

***Reference***
[array_slice()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php)
[array_pop()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php)

Comment: The first solution work. Thanks. I don't want to delete the last item as it has it's own purpose later :D

Answer (score 2):

Use array_pop:

```
$array = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
$last = array_pop($array);
print_r($array);
```

Outputs:

```
Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 [2] => 3 [3] => 4 )
```

PHPFiddle Link: http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/i02x-w9m6

Comment: No, he doesn't. `$array` will result in the thing he wanted.

Answer (score 1):

try `array_pop()` or `array_slice`

```
array_pop($array);
```

or

```
array_slice($array, 0, -1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try [array_pop](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-pop.php) or [array_slice](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php)

```
array_slice($a, 0, -1);
print_r($a);
  // or
$arr = array_pop($a);
print_r($a);
```

for `array_slice` the params are

```
array array_slice ( array $array , int $offset [, int $length = NULL [, bool $preserve_keys = false ]] )
```

in your code you have set the start(offset) as -1 thats why it didn't work

`array_slice($a, 0, -1);` here `$a` is the array `0` the offset or starting point `-1` the length

Answer (score 1):

Array Slice is function, you can use

```
$k = array( "India", "UK", "USA" );

$sliced = array_slice($k, 0, -1); 

print_r($sliced);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => India
    [1] => UK
)
```